# Не работает fill в SVG, добавленный в HTML с помощью background

Tags: html, css, svg

```css
select {
    border: 1px solid #4c4c4c;
    border-radius: 0.25em;
    color: #cfcfcf;
    height: 22px;
    background: url("data:image/svg+xml;utf8,<svg fill='#cfcfcf' height='14' viewBox='0 0 18 22' width='12' xmlns='http://www.w3.org/2000/svg'><path d='M7 10l5 5 5-5z'/><path d='M0 0h24v24H0z' fill='none'/></svg>") no-repeat, linear-gradient(to top, #55565a, #4a4b4e, #55565a);
    background-position: calc(100% - 2px) 49%;
    -moz-appearance:none;
    -webkit-appearance: none;
    appearance: none;
    padding: 0 1.25em 0 0.25em;
}
```

```html
<select>
  <option>Select 1</option>
  <option>Select 2</option>
</select>
```

Comment: https://yoksel.github.io/url-encoder/ru/

Comment: Замените `#` на `%23`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Замените `#` на `%23`.

В следующий раз пользуйтесь инструментом для правильного экранирования символов в SVG

https://yoksel.github.io/url-encoder/ru

```css
select {
    border: 1px solid #4c4c4c;
    border-radius: 0.25em;
    color: #cfcfcf;
    height: 22px;
    background: url("data:image/svg+xml;utf8,<svg fill='%23cfcfcf' height='14' viewBox='0 0 18 22' width='12' xmlns='http://www.w3.org/2000/svg'><path d='M7 10l5 5 5-5z'/><path d='M0 0h24v24H0z' fill='none'/></svg>") no-repeat, linear-gradient(to top, #55565a, #4a4b4e, #55565a);
    background-position: calc(100% - 2px) 49%;
    -moz-appearance:none;
    -webkit-appearance: none;
    appearance: none;
    padding: 0 1.25em 0 0.25em;
}
```

```html
<select>
  <option>Select 1</option>
  <option>Select 2</option>
</select>
```